# How to set variable with list's metadata (like customerID)?

Tags: powershell

How do I set a metadata (say CustomerID or Skills) with PowerShell? I am trying to fill CustID. Please suggest.....

```
$siteURL="http://Server" 
$site=Get-SPSite $siteURL 
$web=$site.RootWeb 
$collFiles=$web.GetFolder("DocLib_OR_List").Files 
$count=$collFiles.Count 

while($count -ne 0)
 {
 $CustID= $collFiles[$count-1]["CustomerID"]
 so forth...... 
}
```

Solved it. Working code:

```
$siteURL="http://Server"
$docLib = "My Doc Lib"
$site=Get-SPSite $siteURL
$web=$site.RootWeb
$collFiles=$web.GetFolder($docLib).Files
$count=$collFiles.Count
while($count -ne 0)
{
$item = $collFiles[$count-1].Item
$DocSet = $item["Region"]
Write-Host "$DocSet is the doc set. $collFiles[$count-1].Name is name"
$collFiles[$count-1].MoveTo($siteURL + "/" + $docLib + "/" + $DocSet + "/"  + $collFiles[$count-1].Name, $true)                       
$count--
}
```

Comment: You may never see this, but since SO is a Q&A site the proper to have handled this would be to leave your question the way it was then post your own answer too it with the correct way to solve the problem. As it is now someone else might wander along doing the same thing that you originally did and never even know that what you posted is actually the solution to their problem.

Comment: Why don't you create an answer and put your solving code inside ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final working code.

```
$siteURL="http://Server"
$docLib = "My Doc Lib"
$site=Get-SPSite $siteURL
$web=$site.RootWeb
$collFiles=$web.GetFolder($docLib).Files
$count=$collFiles.Count
while($count -ne 0)
{
$item = $collFiles[$count-1].Item
$DocSet = $item["Region"]
Write-Host "$DocSet is the doc set. $collFiles[$count-1].Name is name"
$collFiles[$count-1].MoveTo($siteURL + "/" + $docLib + "/" + $DocSet + "/"  + $collFiles[$count-1].Name, $true)                       
$count--
}
```